# Work with DirectoryEntry not on a Domain, set user password never expire

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryentry

I want to put the user password check to never expire. When I create the user, the check is always unchecked.

My code.

```
DirectoryEntry user = root.Children.Add(adUserName, "user");
          // NOTE(cboivin): Documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746340(VS.85).aspx         
          user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { adUserPassword });
          // NOTE(cboivin): Ne pas mettre les clefs dans les ressources, Description, PasswordExpirationDate, AccountExpirationDate
          user.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", Nms.SiteAccess.Business.Manager.ActiveDirectory._resources.WindowsPermissionManager.UserCreerAutomatiquement + args.AddDescriptif });
          user.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "PasswordExpirationDate", args.PasswordExpiration });
          user.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "AccountExpirationDate", args.AccountExpiration });

          user.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384304/creating-local-user-account-c-and-net-2-0) ...

```
user.Invoke("Put", new object[] {"UserFlags", 0x10000});
```