# I (think) I want to use a BItWise Operator to check useraccountcontrol property!

Tags: c#, ldap, bitwise-operators

Here's some code:

```
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.Filter =  "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + lstUsers.SelectedItem.Text + "))";
        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
```

Within result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"] will be an item which will give me a value depending on the state of the account. For instance, a value of 66050 means I'm dealing with:
A normal account; where the password does not expire;which has been disabled.
[Explanation here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144).

What's the most concise way of finding out if my value "contains" the AccountDisable flag (which is 2)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Convert.ToBoolean((int)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"] & 0x0002)
```

Translated from a current code base here, it should work...

Comment: All good answers so far, but thanks Frank - I think you were first!

Answer (score 4):

```
enum AccountFlags
{
    Script = (1<<0),
    AccountDisable = (1<<1),
    // etc...
}

if( ((int)result.Properties["useraccountcontrol"]) & AccountFlags.AccountDisable > 0 )
{
    // Account is Disabled...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UserAccountControlFlags userAccFlags = (UserAccountControlFlags) 66050;

// Much more readable    
if(userAccFlags.Has(UserAccountControlFlags.AccountDisabled))
{
   // Do your stuff here
}
```

And here's the extension method:

```
public static bool Has<T>(this System.Enum type, T value) where T : struct 
{
    return ((int)(object)type & (int)(object)value) > 0;
}
```

Enum definition referred from [C# Online](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Managing_Basic_User_Account_Properties_in_Active_Directory)

```
[Flags]
public enum UserAccountControlFlags
{ 
  Script                             = 0x1,
  AccountDisabled                    = 0x2,
  HomeDirectoryRequired              = 0x8,
  AccountLockedOut                   = 0x10,
  PasswordNotRequired                = 0x20,
  PasswordCannotChange               = 0x40,
  EncryptedTextPasswordAllowed       = 0x80,
  TempDuplicateAccount               = 0x100,
  NormalAccount                      = 0x200,
  InterDomainTrustAccount            = 0x800,
  WorkstationTrustAccount            = 0x1000,
  ServerTrustAccount                 = 0x2000,
  PasswordDoesNotExpire              = 0x10000,
  MnsLogonAccount                    = 0x20000,
  SmartCardRequired                  = 0x40000,
  TrustedForDelegation               = 0x80000,
  AccountNotDelegated                = 0x100000,
  UseDesKeyOnly                      = 0x200000,
  DontRequirePreauth                 = 0x400000,
  PasswordExpired                    = 0x800000,
  TrustedToAuthenticateForDelegation = 0x1000000,
  NoAuthDataRequired                 = 0x2000000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is great [tutorial for Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx)  in general ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384304/creating-local-user-account-c-and-net-2-0)).

Basically you want to check the number with the `&` operator:

```
if( ( result & ACCOUNTDISABLE ) == ACCOUNTDISABLE )
{ .... }
```

You can define `ACCOUNTDISABLE` as a const (like in the table you linked). Or you create an enum for the values. Make sure to assign the right numbers and set a [`[Flags]`-attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).
What you chose depends on how many values you need. When dealing only with ACCOUNTDISABLE and nothing else, a define or const will do.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you may be able to use ActiveDirectory to filter accounts by enabled/disabled status:

```
searcher.Filter =  "(&(objectClass=user)(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
```

or:

```
searcher.Filter =  "(&(objectClass=user)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))";
```

Related MS KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269181

And Another Article: http://www.windowsserverfaq.org/?url=/faq/ADQueries/LDAP-Queries.asp

Comment: +1 Bitwise operator at the query level. Not an exact answer to the question, but the most generally useful nonetheless :D