# C# : how can I create User account remotely?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

what I need to do is:
Create User account on another machine from my machine using C#.
I tried to use DirectoryEntry("WinNt://"....) but it create this account localy in my current machine.
I tried many time to add the destination machine name in this method but no way :S.
also i googled and found many articles illustrated somethings like this but not actual what i need.
any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: you mean a windows user account? which version?

Comment: yes windows user account

Comment: version of what?windows?i am currenly using windows XP Prof SP3 but in the future i need to apply my project in a server running w2K3SP2 or W2K8SP1

Comment: string s_Username = "TestUser";
      string s_Password = "password";
      string s_Description = "Test User Account";

      DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
      // create a new user
      DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(s_Username, "user");
       NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { s_Password });
      NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", s_Description });
      // commit the changes
      NewUser.CommitChanges();
      lblResult.Text = "Success!!";

Comment: I tried to replace Environment.MachineName with the remote machine name>>but it failed.both of these two machines are in the same domain

Comment: @KMan : this link gives me :p;age not found :)

Comment: @Ragaei Mahmoud: Look into [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout:

- [How to add a new user using DirectoryServices](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/addnewuser.aspx)?
- [How to add a user to the local system by using Directory Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306271)?
- [Creating local user account c# and .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384304/creating-local-user-account-c-and-net-2-0/384307#384307)

Alternatively, you can spawn a *TCP server/service* on the server machine, and send commands remotely via messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'd have to go to a little client server architecture where the remote 'server' creates a local user based on the supplied client data.