# System.Web.Securit.Membership,GetUser throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: asp.net, f#

I have a brand new Visual Studio 2015 FSharp project (.NET Framework 4.6/FSharp Core 4.4).  I added a script file and code like this:

```
#r "System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"

open System.Web
open System.Web.Security

let userName = "Jamie"
let user = Membership.GetUser(userName)
```

When I run it, I get:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\App_Data' is denied.
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
>      at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
>      at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)
>      at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
>      at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
>      at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)

I can't believe that I have to install Sql Server and whatnot on my machine to just get the current windows user.  Am I using the wrong namespace?

**Edit 1**

I found this article (bottom answer)
[Creating local user account c# and .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384304/creating-local-user-account-c-sharp-and-net-2-0)

I transposed to F#

```
#r "System.DirectoryServices.dll"
open System
open System.DirectoryServices
let localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://localhost")
let entries = localMachine.Children
let user = entries.Add("NewUser","user")
user.Properties.["FullName"].Add("Local User") |> ignore
user.Invoke("SetPassword","P@ssw0rd")
user.Invoke("Put",[|box "UserFlags"; box 0x10000|])
user.CommitChanges()
```

But I am getting

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
```

I can go into computer management and add a user so I know that my logon user has rights.  When I called  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() I confirmed it was my logon user

Does the fsi run in a different context?

Comment: I think you are experiencing the 'benefits' of the [Provider (not-a-)pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/Providerisnotapattern).

Comment: If you want the current Windows user, you can use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to create a user on the machine.  I ditched ASP.NET in a hot minute (nice blog post BTW).

Comment: I'd assume that you need to run FSI in elevated mode. You can try running `fsi.exe` in an elevated command prompt to test if that helps. Just a wild guess...

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I ran Visual Studio as an admin and the account was created. I verified using the Local Users and Groups MMC snap-in